# VBA code - not giving desired o/p

Tags: vba

Below mentioned code is for removal of rows from Sheet1 which are having numbers in Column A  that are not in sheet2's column A.

Issue:

When it is able to match numbers it works fine ie not deleting but when it is not able to match numbers (ie Sheet1's Colum A's cell say A11 (for row 11) has '123' but it is not there in Column A of Sheet 2) it is deleting that row but it is not working for next row in this case row 12 so if A12 of Sheet1 has 123 (non matching number) it is not deleting.

```
Sub Matching()

Dim S1 As Worksheet, S2 As Worksheet, a As Range

    Set S1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set S2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    For Each a In S1.Range("A1:A1000")
        n = Application.Match(a.Value, S2.Range("A1:A25"), 0)
        If IsError(n) Then
            a.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure I am following how you know that a match is working.  Based on the code I see here, it seems like if it does match, it won't delete a row and if it is not deleting a row when there is no match, there is no difference in behavior.

Comment: @psubsee2003 if sheet2[A1] =1,Sheet2[A2]=2....Sheet2[A25]=25 and Sheet1[A1] =1,Sheet1[A2]= Blank,Sheet1[A3]=72,Sheet1[A4]=25 Output should be : Sheet1[A1]=1, Sheet1[A2]=25 But it is showing Sheet1[A1] =1,Sheet1[A2]=72,Sheet1[A3]=25 ....so issue is if it is finding no match for any cell of Column A it is just bypassing next cell of Column A.

Comment: You were very vague on the details, but I guessed that is what was happening (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18231102/250725) for an explanation of why).  A tip for asking questions in the future, try to be as specific as possible when describing your problem.  It helps people to understand exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are deleting a row and still incrementing the `For...Each`, as result, you end up skipping the row after every deletion.

For example, if `S1.Range("A6")` does not have a match, you delete Row 6.  What happens next is where your problem comes in, the previous range A7 becomes the new A6 so when you increment the counter, you are actually skipping what was in A7.

[image]

So you have to make a change in your loop.  Instead of a `For...Each`, you need to use a `For` loop.  Then you have 2 options, first you can work backwards (which will be a lot easier), or if you have to work forwards, you have to decrement the counter when you delete, but you also have to add some other checks to avoid an infinite loop

**Option 1 (Work backwards):**

```
Sub Matching()

Dim S1 As Worksheet, S2 As Worksheet, a As Long

    Set S1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set S2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    For a = 1000 to 1 Step -1
        n = Application.Match(S1.Range("A" & a).Value, S2.Range("A1:A25"), 0)
        If IsError(n) Then
            S1.Row(a).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Option 2 (Work forwards with additional checks)**

```
Dim S1 As Worksheet, S2 As Worksheet, a As Long, maxRow as Long

    Set S1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set S2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    maxRow = 1000
    For a = 1 To maxRow
        n = Application.Match(S1.Range("A" & a).Value, S2.Range("A1:A25"), 0)
        If IsError(n) Then
            S1.Rows(a).Delete
            a = a - 1           'Decrement counter
            maxRow = maxRow - 1 'Decrement last row to check
        End If

        If a > maxRow Then Exit For 'Safety valve in case last row doesn't match
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your task, it may be faster to separate the deletion from the loop (a sort of flag for deletion and delete after). This has the advantage of not messing your for each loop AND being faster.

Consider something along these lines:

```
For Each rngCell In Range("A1:A1000")
    n = Application.Match(S1.Range("A" & a).Value, S2.Range("A1:A25"), 0)
    If IsError(n) Then
        If (rngDelete Is Nothing) Then
            Set rngDelete = rngCell.EntireRow
        Else
            Set rngDelete = Union(rngDelete, rngCell.EntireRow)
        End If
    End If
Next rngCell
rngDelete.Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Try stepping back through the range instead

```
Sub Matching()

Dim S1 As Worksheet, S2 As Worksheet, a As Long

    Set S1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set S2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    For a = 1000 To 1 Step -1
        n = Application.Match(S1.Range("A" & a).Value, S2.Range("E1:E25"), 0)
        If IsError(n) Then
            S1.Range("A" & a).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

    Next a

End Sub
```